# Does the "unanswered" category work?

Tags: discussion, android-app, unanswered-questions

There are often questions marked as "unanswered" that have already many answers. Does this feature not work, or do "answered" questions have to have an accepted answer?

Comment: Answers only count as when they have a score > 0. So when a question is "unanswered", it means it doesn't have any positive scored answers.

Comment: There must be a duplicate somewhere, let me check.

Comment: @PatrickHofman But the answers often have scores, I would send a screenshot, but I'm not able to upload it in the moment.

Comment: *The Unanswered Questions tab shows questions that have no answers with a positive score nor an accepted answer. (That includes questions with no answers at all.)* See the dup.